# View not updating in Internet Explorer 8 and angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer-8

We are developing a one page application that needs IE8 support. The app itself is pretty simple in its interface (basically a home screen that allows you to choose what form you want to fill, lots of dynamic forms, and a result screen based on what you have filled in the form).

So we implemented the core navigation, tried it in IE8, everything worked, happy (as happy you can be with IE8).

Project moved forward, we implemented all the hardcore form stuff, add CSS and a bit more HTML and... navigation started to behave strangely (in IE8) : some links (not all, adds to the strangeness) don't update the view. The URL updates properly, if you refresh the browser, the page is displayed as it should.

To change pages we use $location (no direct #/whatever) in a navigation service, injected in the controllers. Routing is done with `$routeProvider`.

We followed everything on https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie (`ng-app` and `id` in the html tag, no tag, only attributes, etc). Works perfectly fine in Chrome, FF, Safari. We are using Angular 1.2.16.

Comment: Need more info. Did you introduce something that caused it to stop working? What changed?

Comment: Basicaly, we just kept adding more stuff on what worked. We tried on a couple of forms, then added more and more and more. Other than that, from an angular POV it's prety basic. My only lead so far would be some kind of performance issue that makes angular "derail". We are loading json data that are a bit complex (many nested levels). Those objects are then used in the scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a strange bug, caused by (at least) [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) that made a call to Array.forEach (that IE8 does not support) :

```
function cleanupJQueryElements() {
    var self = this;

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(arguments, function (element) {
        self[element].remove();
        self[element] = null;
    });
}
```

It has been fixed (for some time already) and replaced by

```
$.each(arguments, function (i, element) {
    self[element].remove();
    self[element] = null;
});
```

No error was reported in IE8 itself but we found the issue when running IE11 in IE8 emulated mode (and catching all exceptions, as the original message lacked any indication where the issue where).